# Visual C++ program does not run in other computers?

Tags: c++

I've created a Visual C++ console application(project) because our teacher told us to make a project till the end of the semester and show it to him before the practical exam starts...

But the problem is that when I try to run it on my school computer then is shows an error message of a `.dll` file missing".

In my computer it runs like BOSS. But in my school computer it does not run and keeps showing me the message.

I just can't understand why?? And one thing I forgot to mention is that in our school we use the old Borland compiler I think version 4.5 or something...

Comment: If you can't be bothered to show the actual name of the missing DLL, I can't be bothered to help.

Comment: What is "some" dll? Please be *exact* when reporting messages. I'm guessing it is runtime DLLs for Visual C++. You would need to install them on the target PC, or static link them in your application.

Comment: Title says Visual C++ but question says Borland. Which is it?

Comment: Have you searched The Internet for that error message? This sounds like a common problem, and I get the impression you've given up at the first hurdle.

Comment: I created the program using Visual C++ but in our school we have Borland Compiler...

Comment: That should not make a difference as to failing to find the DLL. It may make a difference if you are trying to link in certain symbols whose names have been mangled differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's missing **msvcrt.dll**. It provides a typical set of library functions required by C and C++ programs. These include string manipulation, memory allocation, C-style input/output calls, etc.

You can link it statically, or install appropriate Visual Studio Redistributable package. Or  just put required dlls in application folder.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So if I install a visual C++ compiler there... then it should do the work fine, right??

Comment: If you don't want to code anything on that computer redistributable package should work fine.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to c++ and I don't know what a redistributable package is...

Comment: It installs runtime components required to run C++ applications build with Visual Studio. If you created project on 2012 you'll need Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable Package, if 2010 VS 2010 Redistributable, and so on. You can download it for free from Microsoft Download Center.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to run a "dependency checker" on your DLL to see what it might use that is missing. It might be a runtime library or something else.
2. How is your application trying to load the DLL? Is it using LoadLibrary or linking in the build, in which case it would link against a .lib files.
3. There might also be some name-mangling issues.